# Drupal session on different host and federated mysql database management

Tags: drupal, authentication, federated

I have two instances of Drupal website www.drupalwebsite1.com and www.drupalwebsite2.com
I am using federated tables  (MySQL ). 
I need to know how to manage session for these two instances so when user login on instance 1 www.drupalwebsite1.com then it will show auto login to www.drupalwebsite2.com there will no need to make separate login.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Drupal uses cookies for session management, so unless third party cookies are enabled in browser, I don't think it will be possible for www.drupalwebsite2.com to access the cookie set by www.drupalwebsite1.com. However, for subdomains, it should work - so site1.drupalwebsite.com and site2.drupalwebsite.com should work.